# Lync 2010 web app Share desktop not available

Tags: desktop, web-applications, share, lync

We are attempting to set up Lync 2010 to organize meetings with external users however when we get the meeting set up there is no option of `Desktop` under the `Share` menu.

I can't find any kind of documentation on this anywhere.

I've checked the settings and desktop sharing looks to be enabled.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your conferencing policy to ensure that `EnableAppDesktopSharing` is set to desktop. Have a look at [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425788.aspx) for reference.